# Unable to print fi in latex

Tags: paragraphs

**fiber** text in paragraph is printed in pdf as **ber** in latex "fi ïs eliminated how to fix it.

In paragraph fiber is displayed as ber in pdf, how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Introduction}
connectivity, which can be either X-DSL or ﬁber. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the compilable code that produces this, but I guess it's something with font or input encoding

Comment: Please give us a full compilable minimal working example so we can test it.  And let us know what command you're using to compile (pdflatex, xelatex etc.).  It's a font issue as "fi" is a ligature - a single character which is missing in your font.  Finding out why is the important part

Comment: The problem is your source code is using unicode `fi` ligature, but you have not enabled it in the output.  delete the `fi` character and replace it with `f` and `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inputing the fi as the unicode character U+FB01. Either replace this by "fi" or use inputenc and define a suitable replacement:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\begin{document} \thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Introduction} connectivity, which can be either X-DSL or ﬁber. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: I didn't saw that you flagged the duplicate.